# How can I get asserts in my iOS framework to just print the filename instead of the entire path?

Tags: ios, nsassert

Say the following assert is hit in my code:

```
NSAssert(NO, @"This assert should always be hit.");
```

At the top of the stack trace, the entire path to the file is printed:

```
Assertion failure in +[Foo barMethod:], /Users/foo/code/SomeFramework/SomeFolder/file.m:12
```

For privacy reasons, is there a simple way by which I can mute the path printed, or just have it print `file.m:16` without affecting the quality of the stack trace?